# Variable in Makefile always evaluates to false

Tags: variables, makefile, evaluate

I am trying to execute a script when a file exist within a makefile.
I tried the solution below as well as `ifdef DRP_FILE` and others, but the ifeq always evaluates to false (see output).

I feel like I am making a mistake with my spacing (tabs/spaces), executing the code as either make commands or shell commands - but I don't know where I am going wrong. And a search didn't reveal anything helpful.

```
# Makefile for testing
# Variables
BASE_DIR ?= $(shell pwd)/..
DRP_ROUTE_APP := app
BOARD:=sample
PLAT:=plat

# Targets
.PHONY: test
test: install-config
    @echo "Test passed!"

install-config:
ifneq ($(DRP_ROUTE_APP),)
    $(eval ROOTFS_OVERLAY:=/projects/$(PLAT)/$(BOARD)/rootfs_overlay)
    $(eval DRP_PATH:=$(shell find $(BASE_DIR)$(ROOTFS_OVERLAY)/etc/sfl/cfg/ -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*.txt'))
    $(eval DRP_FILE:=$(if $(DRP_PATH),$(shell basename $(realpath $(DRP_PATH)))))

    # Debug information
    @echo "DRP_PATH: $(DRP_PATH)"
    @echo "DRP_FILE: $(DRP_FILE)"

    ifeq ($(strip $(DRP_FILE)),)
        $(error "drp route file not found")
    else
        $(MAKE) run-drp-setup
    endif
endif

run-drp-setup:
    @echo "$(BASE_DIR)/./drp_setup.sh -f $(DRP_PATH) -s $(DRP_ROUTE_APP)"
```

Output make -f testmakefile test

```
testmakefile:22: *** "drp route file not found".  Stop.
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix and match "shell commands" and "make commands" like this.  Make doesn't have a shell built in.  It runs a shell as a separate process.  And there's no way for the shell processing and the makefile processing to communicate back and forth as they run.

The way make invokes a recipe is that FIRST, **all** the make constructs in the entire recipe are expanded.  All make variables, all make functions, etc. are all expanded first.  **Then** once that is done and all values are expanded, make will run a shell and give the resulting expanded output to the shell as a set of commands to run.  Then make waits for the shell to exit and  checks its exit code.  If it's 0 then the command succeeded and make continues.  If the exit code is not 0 then make considers that the recipe failed.

So, you just can't combine things like `$(eval ...)`, `$(error ...)`, etc. inside recipes because those things are always expanded first.

Similarly, all make constructs like `ifeq` etc. are *preprocessor* statements in makefiles.  They are processed as the makefile is read in, before make decides which targets even need to be rebuilt much less tries to run recipes.

So in short, if you have things you need to do that rely on shell commands that are run as part of your recipe you must write the entire thing in **shell** syntax.  You cannot use make functions or variables set by eval etc.  But here it doesn't seem like any of this is needed anyway, it just makes your makefile more complicated.  Why don't you just use:

```
# Makefile for testing
# Variables
BASE_DIR ?= $(shell pwd)/..
DRP_ROUTE_APP := app
BOARD := sample
PLAT := plat

ifneq ($(DRP_ROUTE_APP),)
  ROOTFS_OVERLAY := /projects/$(PLAT)/$(BOARD)/rootfs_overlay
  DRP_PATH := $(shell find $(BASE_DIR)$(ROOTFS_OVERLAY)/etc/sfl/cfg/ -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*.txt')
  DRP_FILE := $(if $(DRP_PATH),$(shell basename $(realpath $(DRP_PATH))))
endif

# Targets
.PHONY: test
test: install-config
        @echo "Test passed!"

install-config:
ifneq ($(DRP_ROUTE_APP),)
        @echo "DRP_PATH: $(DRP_PATH)"
        @echo "DRP_FILE: $(DRP_FILE)"
        if test -z '$(strip $(DRP_FILE))'; then \
            echo "drp route file not found"; exit 1; \
        else \
            $(MAKE) run-drp-setup; \
        fi
endif

run-drp-setup:
         @echo "$(BASE_DIR)/./drp_setup.sh -f $(DRP_PATH) -s $(DRP_ROUTE_APP)"
```

Comment: Thanks. Make finally makes some sense after your clarification.
I did not like the output from the `if test -z` during my build, so I changed that slightly to the following. And that seems to work, but I am sure I missed something...
`install-config:
ifneq ($(DRP_ROUTE_APP),)
ifneq ($(DRP_FILE),)
 $(MAKE) run-drp-setup
endif
endif`

Comment: Formatting in makefiles is critical and you can't really format comments in stackoverflow.  But, if I understand what you did correctly it will work.